# Proper Syntax for writing all output of a command using stdin, not just the output of the command

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression, curl

I am trying to send the output of a curl request to a file using regular-expression.

`curl -k -v -x x.x.x.x:x https://repo.nagios.com/nagios/7/repodata/repomd.xml > curl1`

Using the above syntax only writes the output of the request to the file but I would like to see both the setup portion and the output of the curl written to the file.

I know that I could use putty to log all output of the shell but I am specifically looking for a bash solution.

Comment: Most likely the "setup portion" is emitted to stderr, so you'd do `... > output.file 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "curl -k -v https://www.google.com" >> curl1;  curl -k -v https://www.google.com >> curl1
```